# Problem with DTE2 for Running Commands in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, service-provider

I'm trying to make a extension for visual studio after watching a video on Youtube of how to get started. After following some instructions I ran across a littler error when trying to set up the extension for a custom command in the Menu under tools.

`DTE2 dte = (DTE2)ServiceProvider.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE));`

My ServiceProvider is a `IAsyncServiceProvider` rather than `ServiceProvider`. So is there a way I can make a DTE2 object wihtout changing everything from `IAsyncServiceProvider` to `ServiceProvider`.

My Code:

```
<code>       public static async Task InitializeAsync(AsyncPackage package)
        {
            await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);
            OleMenuCommandService commandService = await package.GetServiceAsync((typeof(IMenuCommandService))) as OleMenuCommandService;
            Instance = new FRC(package, commandService);
    }

        public static void ExecuteCommand(DTE2 dte, string commandName)
        {
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
            var command = dte.Commands.Item(commandName);
            if (command.IsAvailable)
            {
                dte.ExecuteCommand(command.Name);
            }
        }

        private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DTE2 dte = package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE2)) as DTE2;
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
            ExecuteCommand(dte, string.Format("View.ClassView"));
        }
    }
</code>
```

His code:
 `var dte = (DTE2)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video you are talking about : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFiRotBsVKU

I used Andre.L solution and its working.

There is two line to change in the code and its in the function

```
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

first by adding to keyword `async` into the function signature

```
private async void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and then by changing this line

```
DTE2 dte = package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE2)) as DTE2;
```

into this

```
var dte = await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE)).ConfigureAwait(false) as DTE2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an async function, try this instead:

```
private async void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dte = await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE));
    DTE2 dte2 = dte2 as DTE2;
    if(dte2 != null){
        ExecuteCommand(dte2, string.Format("View.ClassView"));
    }
}
```

Or, with ConfigureAwait:

```
private async void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DTE2 dte2 = await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE)).ConfigureAwait(false) as DTE2;
    if(dte2 != null){
        ExecuteCommand(dte2, string.Format("View.ClassView"));
    }
}
```